# What is the purpose of micrometer in opentelemetry? or can opentelementry add the traceid and spanid like sleuth, micrometer automatically for logs?

Tags: trace, distributed, micrometer, jaeger

I am recently looking for the distributed tracing solution for my microservice architecture. my microservice architecture involved multiple different types of java application will be running.

I have to provide the observability feature (logs, metrics and tracing) to my microservice solution. I came across multiple possible options like  sleuth (deprecated), micrometer, opentelemetry, zipkin, jaeger, signoz and prometheus for this.

After referring all the blogs, I understood like we can use the above application as a combination, like

```
sleuth + zipkin
micrometer + opentelemetry + jaegar + prometheus
micrometer + opentelemetry + signoz
opentelemetry + zipkin
```

Here, the sleuth and micrometer will be used to generate traceid and span id. micrometer has some extra advantage than sleuth that it supports metrics as well.

My question is, what is the role of opentelemetry here? is opentelemetry requires sleuth or micrometer for adding traceid/spanid? opentelemetry has any inbuild automatic instrumentation for adding traceid/span id?

PS
opentelemetry will act as a bridge between multiple receivers to multiple exporters. but what advantages it additionally provides?

```
Thanks in Advance
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does Micrometer fit in OpenTelemetry project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602266/where-does-micrometer-fit-in-opentelemetry-project)

Answer (score 0):

BLUF: opentelemetry can be used for everything!

You do not need sleuth or micrometer. If available for you language, you can add OTel auto instrumentation to all your apps (for Java it is, via an agent). This will provide a ton of metric and traces for the libs used by your app (e.g. hibernate, kafka). if u then want to create custom metrics/traces within your app, you can again use the OTel API.

So sleuth is dead. Micrometer can do some of the above,. but it has no auto-instrumentation, so u will need to add boilerplate. It only works for Java. The no. of libraries it instruments seems low (7 listed here only - https://micrometer.io/docs). Also, spring boot 3 uses micrometer under the hood. This is surprising to me, since OTel is becoming the standard. I guess they did this since they had such an investment already in this lib. On this though, the OTel auto-instrumentation will translate any micrometer metrics/traces to OTel.

Hope that helps